# Why does C# think EF Include() returns a nullable object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

[The documentation for Include is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbextensions.include?view=entity-framework-5.0.0):

```
public static System.Linq.IQueryable<T> Include<T,TProperty> (this System.Linq.IQueryable<T> source, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T,TProperty>> path) where T : class;
```

But for the line of code:

```
numCountySignups = context.Counties.Include(c => c.Events).ThenInclude(e => e.Signups).First(c => c.Id == county.Id).Events.Sum(ee => ee.Signups.Count);
```

I get the warning:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning CS8620  Argument of type 'IIncludableQueryable<County, ICollection<Event>?>' cannot be used for parameter 'source' of type 'IIncludableQueryable<County, IEnumerable<Event>>' in 'IIncludableQueryable<County, ICollection<Signup>?> EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ThenInclude<County, Event, ICollection<Signup>?>(IIncludableQueryable<County, IEnumerable<Event>> source, Expression<Func<Event, ICollection<Signup>?>> navigationPropertyPath)' due to differences in the nullability of reference types.  IntegrationTests    C:\git\LouisHowe\IntegrationTests\repository\TestCounty.cs  203 Active
```

which goes away if I add a ! as follows:

```
numCountySignups = context.Counties.Include(c => c.Events)!.ThenInclude(e => e.Signups).First(c => c.Id == county.Id).Events.Sum(ee => ee.Signups.Count);
```

As the declaration of Include() shows it to be non-nullable, why do I get this warning?

Comment: I don’t believe the API is nullable-aware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation reference you included was from EF 5 (.Net Framework) rather than EF Core. NRTs can be problematic in EF with compiler warnings, especially with EF Core prior to 6.0. If you are running EF Core 5 then you should look to upgrade to EF Core 6 or 7.

One detail is to ensure that all collection navigation properties are initialized in your entities:

```
public class County
{
    // ...

    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; private set; } = new List<Event>();
}
```

Lastly, the example query you provided is a particularly inefficient way to get the Sum:

```
numCountySignups = context.Counties
    .Include(c => c.Events)
        .ThenInclude(e => e.Signups)
    .First(c => c.Id == county.Id)
    .Events.Sum(ee => ee.Signups.Count);
```

This loads all events and signups for the given county into memory just to get a sum of the signup count. Instead:

```
numCountySignups = context.Counties
    .Where(c => c.Id == county.Id)
    .Select(c => c.Events.Sum(ee => ee.Signups.Count))
    .First();
```

This would build and execute an SQL statement against the database to retrieve just that sum.

Comment: I very much appreciate your answer. And the better way to get the count is very helpful, not only for this use but other queries I have. Can you also please provide details about why I get the warning too? I [found the EF6 documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbextensions.include?view=entity-framework-5.0.0&viewFallbackFrom=entity-framework-6.2.0) and it also does shows Include() to be non-nullable. TIA

Comment: I want to say thank you again. I reviewed my high volume queries and found a set where I could make them much more efficient (using Any(), not Sum()) and that's due to your suggestion above. So again, very appreciated.